# Linux buffer cache effect on IO writes?

Tags: linux, caching, file-io, linux-kernel

I'm copying large files (3 x 30G) between 2 filesystems on a Linux server (kernel 2.6.37, 16 cores, 32G RAM) and I'm getting poor performance. I suspect that the usage of the buffer cache is killing the I/O performance.

I've written a small C program to replicate the problem. The program writes 20G of zero bytes directly to a SAS disk (/dev/sda, no filesystem). It also supports the O_DIRECT flag.

When I run the program with O_DIRECT a get a very steady and predictable performance:

```
/dev/sda:   100M current_rate=195.569950M/s avg_rate=195.569950M/s  
/dev/sda:   200M current_rate=197.063362M/s avg_rate=196.313815M/s  
/dev/sda:   300M current_rate=200.479145M/s avg_rate=197.682893M/s  
/dev/sda:   400M current_rate=210.400076M/s avg_rate=200.715853M/s  
...  
/dev/sda: 20100M current_rate=206.102701M/s avg_rate=201.217154M/s  
/dev/sda: 20200M current_rate=206.485716M/s avg_rate=201.242573M/s  
/dev/sda: 20300M current_rate=197.683935M/s avg_rate=201.224729M/s  
/dev/sda: 20400M current_rate=200.772976M/s avg_rate=201.222510M/s
```

Without O_DIRECT is a different story:

```
/dev/sda:   100M current_rate=1323.171377M/s avg_rate=1323.171377M/s  
/dev/sda:   200M current_rate=1348.181303M/s avg_rate=1335.559265M/s  
/dev/sda:   300M current_rate=1351.223533M/s avg_rate=1340.740178M/s  
/dev/sda:   400M current_rate=1349.564091M/s avg_rate=1342.935321M/s  
...  
/dev/sda: 20100M current_rate=67.203804M/s avg_rate=90.685743M/s  
/dev/sda: 20200M current_rate=68.259013M/s avg_rate=90.538482M/s  
/dev/sda: 20300M current_rate=64.882401M/s avg_rate=90.362464M/s  
/dev/sda: 20400M current_rate=65.412577M/s avg_rate=90.193827M/s
```

I understand that the initial throughtput is high because that data is cached and committed later to disk. However I don't expect the overall performance using the buffer cache to be 50% less than with O_DIRECT.

I also did tests with dd, I get similar results (I used 10G though here instead of 20G):

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=32K count=327680 oflag=direct
327680+0 records in
327680+0 records out
10737418240 bytes (11 GB) copied, 54.0547 s, 199 MB/s

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=32K count=327680             
327680+0 records in
327680+0 records out
10737418240 bytes (11 GB) copied, 116.993 s, 91.8 MB/s
```

Are there any kernel tunings that could fix/minimize the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this community is mean for programming related questions. Though I find this question quite interesting, I'd recommend moving it to serverfault.com.

Comment: I am also voting to move, in a "best of both worlds" kind of way. Questions here get answered very quickly if they get answered at all. If you don't have an answer by the time the question is moved, you'll get a second chance on serverfault.

Comment: THanks, I'll post my question there instead.

Comment: The question at serverfault is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/238879/linux-buffer-cache-effect-on-io-writes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer cache is quite efficient, even when buffering huge amounts of data.

Running your dd test on an enterprise SSD, I can easily do over 1GBps of 32KB writes through the buffer cache.

I find your results interesting, but I don't think your problem is "buffer cache too slow".

My first question would be: is it slow because you're CPU-limited or disk-limited?  Check if you have one CPU core pegged at 100% during the test-- this might indicate that there's something wrong at the driver or block level, like an I/O elevator that's misbehaving.  If you find a core pegged run some profiles to see what that core is up to.

If you're disk-limited you might want to investigate what the I/Os look like at the device level (use blktrace?) and see if you can figure out if the resulting I/O pattern gives poor performance at the device level.

Also, you might want to consider using something like `fio` to run your tests, instead of inventing your own benchmark program-- it'll be easier for others to reproduce your results and trust your program isn't at fault.

Comment: Following the advise of others I posted the question at serverfault here: http://serverfault.com/questions/238879/linux-buffer-cache-effect-on-io-writes. The fio output is included there.

Comment: Does reducing /sys/block/sd*/queue/max_sectors_kb help?  How about different schedulers?  ( /sys/block/sd*/queue/scheduler )

Comment: Changing max_sectors_kb didn't change much, and I had already tried different schedulers before wit no success.